# Set of an Unordered Data Type with a given ordering

Tags: haskell, set

I'm trying to put this data type in a Haskell Set, but I don't want to give it a general instance of Ord. So I want to give the set an ordering on y-coördinate but without instance Ord Vector. Is this possible?

```
    data Vector = V 
    { x :: Double
    , y :: Double
    } deriving (Eq)
```

Comment: Can you store the coordinates as a tuple `(y, x)`?

Comment: I could do that, but what does that help me?
Actually I want to use different orderings in different functions (one time x-coordinate, one time the y-coordinate) and later on I want to expand it in more dimensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Set` requires you to use the default `Ord` instance of the element type.

If you want to use a different `Ord` instance, the standard way to do that is to use a custom `newtype` wrapper and then write an `Ord` instance for that:

```
newtype Y = Y { unY :: Vector } deriving Eq
instance Ord Y where compare = comparing ((y . unY) &&& (x . unY))
```

But since this way of comparing is equivalent to the way binary tuples are compared, KennyTM's solution is the simplest here.

Comment: Nice.  I was just typing in the exact same thing.

Comment: I can get it to work but i don't fully understand what I'm typing.
So i figured i can replace &&& by (\l -> ((y.unY l),(x.unY l))). But i don't really see how this is a function Num => b->a (i'm getting this signature out of the documentation of comparing)
Can you rewrite this in lower-lever Haskell? I'm still a bit of a newbie in Haskell

Comment: @Ingdas: Where did you get `Num`? The signature of `comparing` is `Ord  a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering` (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing)

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the vector into a tuple:

```
toTuple :: Vector -> (Double, Double)
toTuple (V x y) = (y, x)

fromTuple :: (Double, Double) -> Vector
fromTuple (y, x) = V x y
```

Since tuples derive Ord (using lexicographic comparison), they can be inserted to the Set. (Define 2 other functions for x-major ordering.)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a version of the `Set` datatype which does not have the `Ord` context, but instead needs a function of type `a -> a -> Ordering` passed in wherever a `Set` is constructed. Could that be useful in your case?

(I'm not sure about the copyright status, it's largely untested and the documentation is not modified, so I'm not just putting it up here...)

Comment: Can you send it to me? ingdas (at) gmail (dot) com
That's actually exactly what I needed

Comment: -1. By posting this kind of answer, you may help the OP but you don't help the whole community.

Comment: Good point, jfpoilpret. I'll get to work on getting it in a releasable state on GitHub so everyone can benefit. ETA somewhere next week, I hope.

Comment: Have you released your implementation yet?